# Chart.js: change title/legend positon to right

Tags: charts, chart.js

I have a bar chart with a title on top. How can I go about changing the legend’s position to right of the chart. I searched on other forums but couldn’t find anything. Here is my code:

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
                labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Votes',
                        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                }, {
                        label: 'Score',
                        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)'
                }]
        },
        options: {
                scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true
                                }
                        }]
                }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set legend­*'s* `position` property to `right` in your chart options, to place the legend at the right side of the chart ...

```
options: {
   legend: {
      position: 'right'
   },
   ...
}
```

---

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Votes',
         data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'
      }, {
         label: 'Score',
         data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      legend: {
         position: 'right'
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your promt answer. Exactly what I needed!